# CQ5 response.sendRedirect with dispatcher is not redirecting to the page

Tags: aem

Have implemented a custom `404.jsp` for error handling, which will capture the URL and if it does not matches a particular pattern, it will redirect to a site for eg: `www.google.com`

This logic works fine in publish instance.
But in dispatcher its not redirecting to the desired page.

Should i do some dispatcher config to do redirect as if in publish?

Comment: How does your `404.jsp` look like ? Can you add some code ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set DispatcherPassError to ‘0’ in dispatcher. If not set, dispatcher will handle all errors without coming to AEM and your 404.jsp will not get invoked. [ACS commons](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/errorpagehandler.html) have a good error handler. Switching this parameter in dispatcher is the key

Comment: Hi Added this parameter in config. even though its not solved